# MySQL shutdown issue on Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, magento2, mysql-error-1064

We have a magento website

Our website some times it showing below error like

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 855613014442

Based on our logs, it is showing that Mysql is going down as shown below

```
2019-06-24T04:44:49.542168Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.26'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2019-06-24T04:44:50.594943Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190624  4:44:50
2019-06-24T04:45:11.103402Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-06-24T04:45:11.103429Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-06-24T04:45:11.103438Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-06-24T04:45:11.103444Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-06-24T04:45:11.103484Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
```

We have increased innodb_buffer_pool_size but still i am facing same issue.

I have executed below commands in my server..check it these outputs

```
1)free -m

Output:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7819        1430        4688          81        1701        6009
Swap:             0           0           0


2)dmesg | tail -30

Output:

[    6.222373] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[    6.241079] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[    6.255768] [drm] fb mappable at 0xF0000000
[    6.259225] [drm] vram aper at 0xF0000000
[    6.262574] [drm] size 33554432
[    6.265475] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    6.268473] [drm]    pitch is 3072
[    6.289079] fbcon: cirrusdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.346169] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    6.347151] loop: module loaded
[    6.357709] cirrus 0000:00:02.0: fb0: cirrusdrmfb frame buffer device
[    6.364646] [drm] Initialized cirrus 1.0.0 20110418 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    6.722341] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input4
[    6.788110] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    6.802845] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.841332] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    6.871200] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    6.873349] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    6.936609] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    6.949717] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    6.964446] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    6.984659] alg: No test for __generic-gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-generic-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    7.084148] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    7.086591] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    7.088788] intel_rapl: DRAM domain energy unit 15300pj
[    7.102115] EDAC sbridge: Seeking for: PCI ID 8086:6fa0
[    7.102119] EDAC sbridge:  Ver: 1.1.2
[    7.175339] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   10.728980] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   10.772307] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)

3)ps auxw | grep mysql

Output:

mysql     5056  2.9 10.8 7009056 871240 ?      Sl   12:29   0:12 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
root      5538  0.0  0.0 112708   976 pts/0    S+   12:36   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Can anyone has idea how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of these commands: `free -m`  
`dmesg | tail -30`
`ps auxw | grep mysql`
?

Comment: I think you have to optimize mysql query so It not take more load on mysql server.

Comment: Hi Jinesh
Our website configured with magento2 with mysql database.
Actually problem with mysql server sometimes disconnected.

Comment: @qwertz I run the commands that what you suggested, I got the outputs like above please check once, Edit my question with outputs for the command